# How to clean a smelly flute?

Tags: maintenance, flute

I've been playing the flute for a while, an noticed that my flute headjoint is smelling a little funky. How do I clean it, and is it safe to wash the headjoint (after removing the cork)?

P.S. - I have a silver-plated nickel flute.

Comment: No, that question refers to just cleaning the inside of the flute. My question is not how to clean, but deodorise the inside of the flute.

Comment: The accepted answer is about cleaning your flute so I can't see why it isn't a duplicate of the one linked.

Comment: There is no accepted answer and the questionis for how to clean the flute. I know how to clean it, but my question is how to deoderise it. This information is not given in the answers of that question.

Comment: The answer you accepted is about just cleaning a flute which is the same thing the other answers go over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials for cleaning instruments online, for example:

- [Taylor Music's "Piccolo / Flute Cleaning Instructions"](http://www.1800usaband.com/page/view/60)
- [UNLV School of Music's "Instrument Hygiene"](https://www.unlv.edu/music/instrument-hygiene)
- [Jennifer Cluff's "How to Clean a Flute"](http://jennifercluff.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/how-to-clean-flute.html)

In summary though, a cloth and a small amount of rubbing alcohol should be enough to clean your flute once the cork is removed. If rubbing alcohol does not work, it might be worth taking your flute to someone who cleans and repairs instruments like flutes professionally (similar to having a guitar set up or a piano retuned). Getting a professional to give it a thorough clean is almost always worth it, and they may offer some professional advice on instrument maintenance for the future if you ask.